# Recover files from a deleted and erased external disk partition

Tags: backup, time-machine, partition, data-recovery, file-recovery

I had an external disk with two volumes:

- Volume A was formatted as NTFS which had videos/photos backed up
- Volume B was Mac Extended Journaled - which was used for Mac Time Machine backup.

However, Time Machine wasn't working, so I formatted/erased Volume B - not sure what exactly happened, but the NTFS volume was gone too, and now there is just the Mac volume. The NTFS volume with video/photo backup is gone.

Is there a way I can get back at least some of the data from that NTFS volume? It had years of backup of videos/photos.

Note:

- Original HDD was 1 TB with 2 volumes of 500GB
- Now there's just one Mac formatted volume that covers whole HDD of 1 TB

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use recovery software like [DiskDrill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/lp/data-recovery-software.html).

Comment: Can you tell me the macOS version you 'have/had' on you Mac device?
Also, that 1TB partition that you see, what file system is it formatted in?